Слияние одинаковых массивов PHP с заполнением значений если не пустое
Всем доброго времени суток!
Имею два массива. Первый со значениями по некоторым складам [free_to_sell_amount], а второй со всеми складами но пустыми значениями [free_to_sell_amount].
Пытаюсь объединить их, чтобы в результате получить массив по всем складам и заполненными значениями из второго массива, там где есть.
Первый массив со складами где есть остатки (free_to_sell_amount)
Array
    (
        [sku] => 1312583660
        [item_code] => 774420-10
        [item_name] => 774420 Legrand Valena / Розетка белая 2К+З (10шт) ОригиналРитейлГрупп
        [stock] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => ХОРУГВИНО_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 0
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 1
                        [reserved_amount] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => Новосибирск_РФЦ_НОВЫЙ
                        [promised_amount] => 0
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 7
                        [reserved_amount] => 0
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => Екатеринбург_РФЦ_НОВЫЙ
                        [promised_amount] => 0
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 11
                        [reserved_amount] => 0
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => САМАРА_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 0
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 18
                        [reserved_amount] => 0
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => СОФЬИНО_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 0
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 24
                        [reserved_amount] => 0
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => СПБ_ШУШАРЫ_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 0
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 24
                        [reserved_amount] => 0
                    )

            )

    )

Второй массив (со всеми складами, но пустыми значениями free_to_sell_amount)
Array
    (
        [sku] => 1312583660
        [item_code] => 774420-10
        [item_name] => 774420 Legrand Valena / Розетка белая 2К+З (10шт) ОригиналРитейлГрупп
        [stock] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => ХОРУГВИНО_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => Санкт_Петербург_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => САМАРА_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => ПЕТРОВСКОЕ_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => СОФЬИНО_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => ПУШКИНО_1_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => Новосибирск_РФЦ_НОВЫЙ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => Екатеринбург_РФЦ_НОВЫЙ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => СПБ_ШУШАРЫ_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => Ростов_на_Дону_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => НОВОРОССИЙСК_МРФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => ЖУКОВСКИЙ_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => ПУШКИНО_2_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [13] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => АДЫГЕЙСК_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [14] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => НОГИНСК_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [15] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => ВОРОНЕЖ_2_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [16] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => ГРИВНО_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

                [17] => Array
                    (
                        [warehouse_name] => ТВЕРЬ_РФЦ
                        [promised_amount] => 
                        [free_to_sell_amount] => 
                        [reserved_amount] => 
                    )

            )

    )

Хочу получить такой массив
Array
        (
            [sku] => 1312583660
            [item_code] => 774420-10
            [item_name] => 774420 Legrand Valena / Розетка белая 2К+З (10шт) ОригиналРитейлГрупп
            [stock] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => ХОРУГВИНО_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 1
                            [reserved_amount] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => Санкт_Петербург_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 0
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => САМАРА_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 18
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => ПЕТРОВСКОЕ_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 0
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => СОФЬИНО_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 24
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => ПУШКИНО_1_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 0
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => Новосибирск_РФЦ_НОВЫЙ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 7
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => Екатеринбург_РФЦ_НОВЫЙ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 11
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => СПБ_ШУШАРЫ_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 24
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => Ростов_на_Дону_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 0
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => НОВОРОССИЙСК_МРФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 0
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => ЖУКОВСКИЙ_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 0
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => ПУШКИНО_2_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 0
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => АДЫГЕЙСК_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 0
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => НОГИНСК_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 0
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [15] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => ВОРОНЕЖ_2_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 0
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => ГРИВНО_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 0
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                    [17] => Array
                        (
                            [warehouse_name] => ТВЕРЬ_РФЦ
                            [promised_amount] => 0
                            [free_to_sell_amount] => 0
                            [reserved_amount] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

Делаю так, но нечего не выходит
$general_array = array_merge($array1, $array2);


Язык программирования - это не маг и не всевышний. Он не знает, что у вас в голове задумано. Он более приметивен. Поэтому ему надо сказать, что вы от него хотите. И в текущем случае надо напрямую делать цикл и заполнять.......... Причём скорее всего надо два цикла, в случае, если в одном из массивов нет warehouse_name из другого

То есть, цикл с условиями и набирать в новый массив все?

А каким циклом правильнее For или Foreach?

Именно так ​

В данном случае проще foreach...Т.к. надо по всем элементам бежать

Хорошо, попробую так. Благодарю тебя!
Но если у кого то будет желание потренироваться, я с радостью посмотрю его решение тоже)
